# Is it possible to copy a range without the zero-value cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this column of data in excel:

```
0
0
26.49
26.72
26.48
26.45
26.52
26.36
26.4
26.5
26.47
26.48
26.4
0
26.9
26.14
26.18
26.81
26.4
0
```

Is it possible to just copy the non-zero values when the user presses ctrl + c to copy the data?

Comment: Lol, my bad. Was typing in a hurry. Edited

Comment: Yes it is possible but then you will have to use VBA and hook Ctrl + C which can be messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but it can get messy. Here is one way to do it. Make sure to assign a non-critical shortcut to it. <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-C</kbd>, possibly, but YMMV.

```
Sub ModifiedCopy()
    Dim RngToCopy As Range, Rng As Range, Cell As Range
    Set Rng = Selection
    LRow = Rng.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each Cell In Range(Rng.Cells(1, 1), Rng.Cells(LRow, 1))
        If Cell.Value <> 0 And Len(Cell.Value) > 0 Then
            If RngToCopy Is Nothing Then
                Set RngToCopy = Cell
            Else
                Set RngToCopy = Union(RngToCopy, Cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
    RngToCopy.Copy
End Sub
```

You should see the ants around the non-zero, non-null cells in your selection.

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: This helped alot. I've managed to modify it slightly for my needs. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @user3163920: Thanks for accepting. Be careful though, as this is actually useful for single columns. Let us know if you want to handle multiple columns. Also, in "rectangular" cells with data, data has to be contiguous because `Copy` cannot work on non-contiguous multi-dimensional (x and y) group of values. :)